# Karma Jasmine test code inside <script></script>

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I',m learning AngularJS and how to unit test it.

I'm using Karma -> Jasmine and **the test works fine if I test a .js file**.

Karma.conf.js

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Sat Oct 31 2015 16:45:09 GMT-0600 (CST)

...
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'angular.js',
  'angular.min.js',
  'angular-mocks.js',
  'controllerSpec.js',
  'Controller.js'  //WORKS
],
....
```

So if I move the javascript code from the Controller.js file to a `<Script>` block in Controller.cshtml file

```
...
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'angular.js',
  'angular.min.js',
  'angular-mocks.js',
  'controllerSpec.js',
  'Controller.cshtml'  //DOESN'T WORK
],
....
```

When I run the test Karma it throws:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected tokem ILLEGAL at //Controller.cshtml:1
```

**Is it possible to test javascript code inside `<script></script>` in your html file?**

Comment: Damn I wish someone would have answered this, just came across this need myself today.